# Problems while compiling ncmpcpp [configure: error: libmpdclient >= 2.1 is required!]

Tags: snow-leopard, install, open-source, macos

I am trying to compile ncmpcpp|mpd in Snow Leopard 10.6.8, but it failed, since libmpdclient 2.1 dependency is missing. I didn't find any working dependency for libmpdclient 2.1 that uses the gcc compiler coming with Xcode/Apple Developer Tools [3.2.6], so I can't compile it either.

Also I don't use homebrew, fink, mac ports etc.. right now.

The last four lines of the compiling-process [[see complete log/output]](http://pastebin.com/6Jscn47V):

> checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
>      checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
>      checking for libmpdclient... **no**
>      **configure: error: libmpdclient >= 2.1 is required!**

Can anyone provide a source for libmpdclient eventually?

Comment: I `edited` your `question` because your `code` formating was `wrong`. It is `hard` to read if `you` put code blocks `on` non `code` words. Names `of` libraries are `not code`

Comment: An answer to this question would be even nicer, but thank you for editing!

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know how to answer your question. You could offer a bounty on your question, or maybe re-ask?